# Using Proxy server for Java application

Tags: java, oracle, proxy

So i have a java app that uses Google Analytics API to gather some info. I am putting this application to run in my oracle cloud managed server which has a firewall and blocks any web calls to work. So, they setup a proxy for me to use....I've never set up a proxy to work with a java application before, I've been reading at tutorials like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/net/proxies.html

And i have no idea how to set this up...anyone want to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You must tell your application that there's a proxy somewhere.

As the documentation says, you must set some properties in your virtual machine. You can do it programatically:

```
//Set the http proxy to webcache.mydomain.com:8080
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webcache.mydomain.com");
System.setPropery("http.proxyPort", "8080");

// Next connection will be through proxy.
URL url = new URL("http://java.sun.com/");
InputStream in = url.openStream();

// Now, let's 'unset' the proxy.
System.clearProperty("http.proxyHost");

// From now on http connections will be done directly.
```

Or use https.proxy... if the connection is HTTPS.
Besides, if you have access to the application server start script, you could add those properties as VM properties with -Dhttp.proxyHost....

Comment: Would you recommend that i put these statements at the top of my program's code?

Comment: The good solution for me would be to make a config file for your application with that information (proxy host & port), then in the code read that file and set the value of those properties. If you're using Spring, you could set those variables in your applicationContext file.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in my case was to configure the JVM with a HTTPS proxy:

```
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "proxy");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "3128");
```